# Criar tabela html e zebrar a mesma

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber, como eu faço para zebrar uma tabela HTML? Ela tem duas colunas apenas e as informações são preenchidas dinamicamente proveniente da controller e do BD.

Comment: Ponto de partida => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173/como-mudar-o-fundo-das-linhas-de-uma-tabela-alternadamente-com-suporte-pra-nave

Comment: O pnet tem que dar metade do salário p/ o povo do SOpt :)

Comment: bigown, achei que aqui fosse um forum, por isso eu tenho feito vários posts, de tudo aquilo que eu não sei fazer. Mas se caso haja restrição a isso, é só falar que eu paro. Agora, uma vez fiz um comentário tipo esse, sem nada a ver, me censuraram. Ainda bem, bigown, que aqui tem mais pessoas com espírito altruísta que egoísta, isso me faz crer no forum. Aprendi que, se não sabe algo, pergunte, mas não durma com dúvida.

Comment: @pnet tire suas dúvidas a vontade, mas o ideal é que você apresente alguma dúvida dentro de algo que você já produziu. Exemplo: "Já tentei isso mas não está como eu quero, o que eu faço para conseguir deixar como eu quero?". Essa pergunta é uma pergunta típica dos SOpt, mostra que você já tentou alguma coisa e está tendo dificuldades em continuar. Por isso existe a possibilidade de fechar perguntas duplicadas aqui, se não teríamos a mesma pergunta feita dezenas de vezes como na maioría dos fóruns.

Comment: Mas continue perguntando @pnet, estamos aqui para ajudar, ajudar inclusive a fazer um bom uso da comunidade.

Comment: Ok, pode não ir na pergunta o que vc respondeu, mas garanto, talvez com raras exceções que eu posto após tentar. Às vezes já fiz perguntas no momento da dúvida, pois preciso manter meu emprego também e aí o cara me pressiona e eu espirro, claro que vocês não tem nada a ver com isso. É que em outros foruns nunca vi ninguém reclamar de um usuário fazer várias perguntas. E quando olharem a base de conhecimento, vão dizer. Se não fosse o @pnet........, rs

Comment: pnet Leve na brincadeira o que o @bigown. Num ambiente de trabalho descontraído esta é uma piada comum quando alguém recebe ajuda. ;)

Comment: Aqui não é um um fórum, é um site de perguntas e respostas.

Comment: Ok, se saiu bem. Merece metade do meu salário. Só me passe, banco, agência e conta, para fazer uma ted. Mas posso te enviar uma Land Rover, que equivale a metade do meu salário o preço dela. Aí cara, pode parecer mal, mas não leve para o lado escuro da força o meu comentário. Ontem estava chateado, mas hoje, sem mágoas. Estou aqui pela programação e nada mais. Acredite ou não, isso é passado e vamos as perguntas, que tenho bastante. Talvez eleve o percentual do meu salário, rs.

Comment: pnet, conseguiu resolver a criação de sua tabela?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A pseudo-classe nth-child seleciona elementos dentre uma árvore de elementos se referindo a posição específica de cada um. Você pode por exemplo selecionar os elementos ímpares ou pares.

```
tr:nth-child(2n+2) {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

O cálculo utilizado pelo nth-child é bastante simples. Você vai usar na maioria das vezes soma. Lembra? A fómula será a seguinte: an+b.

O funcionamento é o seguinte: o browser aplica o estilo a cada 2 tr.

Você pode facilitar, utilizando as palavras odd ou even, para selecionar os elementos ímpares ou pares da árvore.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Se o valor de a (an+b) é igual 0, você não precisa colocar a fórmula, apenas o número referente a ordem do elemento. Exemplo:

```
table tbody tr:nth-child(1) {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

fonte: [**Propriedade do CSS: nth-child**](http://tableless.com.br/nth-child)
Exemplo funcionando: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w96k8)

### Este seletor possui compatibilidade com os seguinte browsers:

**Desktop**

- Chrome       -   1.0
- Firefox (Gecko)  -   3.5 (1.9.1)
- Internet Explorer    -   9.0
- Opera        -   9.5
- Safari       -   3.1

**Mobile**

- Android          -   2.1
- Firefox Mobile (Gecko)   -   1.0 (1.9.1)
- IE Mobile            -   9.0
- Opera Mobile         -   9.5
- Safari Mobile    -       3.1

Comment: posta o que tu fez pra poder ver o que aconteceu e poder identificar algum possível erro

Comment: De preferência, mas se postar como comentário ainda da pra acompanhar os '*logs*' da discução.

Comment: Você não precisa deste `td`, `tr:nth-child(2n+2) { background: #ccc; }` é suficiente, se vc quiser fazer uma zebra vertical basta trocar o `tr` por um `td` e vai ficar assim `td:nth-child(2n+2) { background: #ccc; }`

Comment: Fica assima  zebra vertical
http://jsfiddle.net/cG3UK/2/

Comment: Eu removi o td da resposta, ele podia estar causando conflito com algum outro estilo que você tivesse na sua app

Comment: para zebrar as colunas você usa `td:nth-child(2n+2) { background: #ccc; }` e para zebrar as linhas você usa `tr:nth-child(2n+2) { background: #ccc; }`

Comment: Como a pergunta não deixou claro se a solução pode ser especifica para ```CSS3``` acho pertinente adicionar os navegadores que suportam estes seletores.

Comment: Está assim o meu e nada. A classe .tblGrid é a tabela que eu quero zebrar. Ainda não funfa.table.tblGrid {
    background:#fff;
    width:100%;
}
tr:nth-child(2n+2) {
    background:#ccc;
}

Comment: tenta colocar assim `.tblGrid tr:nth-child(2n+2) { background:#ccc; }`

Comment: Nada, troquei de class para id e mesmo assim não zebra.

Comment: Cara isso tá muito estranho, tenta reproduzir o seu cenário no **http://jsfiddle.net**, a única coisa q eu consigo pensar agora é seu monitor estar com excesso de brilho e por isso vc não estar conseguindo ver as zebras...

Comment: @pnet conseguiu fazer?

Answer (score 4):

Você tem algumas opções. Com CSS 3 você pode usar `nth-child(even)` e `nth-child(odd)` pra referenciar as linhas ímpares e pares e as celulas dentro dessas linhas. Então você teria o estilo para `tr:nth-child(even)` e analogamente para o `odd`. Veja sobre isso [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Outra solução é usando jQuery: você pode usar as construções acima no jQuery pra selecionar os elementos. Basicamente você selecionaria `$("table tr:nth-child(even)")` e análogo para o `odd` também.

A solução com CSS 3 é mais interessante (na minha opinião) por manter o estilo do site/app no CSS. O problema é que não vai funcionar em navegadores mais antigos que não tenham suporte ao recurso. Nesses casos, se for um requisito seu suportar navegadores mais antigos a solução com jQuery pode ser mais interessante.

Answer (score 1):

Uma Alternativa e utilizar jquery em seu projeto voce pode utilizar dessa forma

```
function zebrar() {
    $('table th').css('background-color', 'green');
    $('table tbody tr:even').css('background-color', '#efe3e');
    $('table tbody tr:odd').css('background-color', 'silver');
}
```

simples e prático