# Alternar cores na tabela com PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Tenho um código que exibe uma tabela em lista dos `ID's` registrados, e pra enfeitar, o código faz com que exiba 1 em 1 alternando as cores entre branco e cinza.

1. COR -> Branco
2. COR -> Cinza
3. COR -> Branco
4. COR -> Cinza ...

Como posso fazer com que uma estrutura de repetição `while` faça a mesma coisa?

```
<?php
   $sqln = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",".$max."");
   $num = mysql_num_rows($sqln);
   for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){
     $tituloP = @mysql_result($sqln, $i, "titulo");
     $n = $i + 1;
     $d = $i % 2;
     if($d == 0){$cor = "cinza";}else{$cor = "claro";}
     print '<tr class='.$cor.'><td> align="center">'.$tituloP.'</td><tr>';
   }

?>
```

Não sei se faz diferença, só que agora estou utilizando `mysqli`.

```
<?php
   $sqln = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.",".$max."");
   mysqli_close($conn);
   while($num_q = mysqli_fetch_array($sqln)){
      $tituloP = $num_q['titulo'];
      print '<tr class=' /*COR*/'><td align="center">'.$tituloP.'</td><tr>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: Não poste o código fonte como imagem.

Comment: [Como mudar o fundo das linhas de uma tabela alternadamente? Com suporte pra navegadores antigos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173/91)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @rray, mas já consegui resolver o problema com a resposta do Kup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes fazer o mesmo, mas colocas um counter,

```
$index = 0;   
while(...) {

    if($index%2==0){ echo 'class="branco"'; }
    else { echo 'class="cinza"'; }

    $index++;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @kup

Answer (score 5):

É possível fazer somente com CSS utilizando o seletor [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Remover rotinas de formatação do seu código PHP facilita a leitura e a manutenção

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
 <th>Number</th>
 <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>Eve Jackson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>John Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>Adam Johnson</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```